# Can I tell UglifyJS to only compress and mangle all files except some which I only want concatenated?

Tags: gruntjs, uglifyjs

Is it possible to specify and array of files that I want compressed and mangled (default Uglify behavior), but also a list of files that should not be touched, just concatenated?

Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can solve this in different ways. I'm posting an extended example to illustrate what one can do:

```
uglify: {
    doAll: {
        options: {
            banner: '// <%= pkg.name %> - v<%= pkg.version %> - ' + '<%= grunt.template.today("yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss") %>\n\n',
            mangle: {
                except: [ // mangle is true for all else besides the specified exceptions
                    'src/input-d.js',
                    'src/input-e.js',
                    'src/input-f.js'
                ]
            },
            preserveComments: 'some'
        },
        files: 'dest/output.min.js': [ // concatenation, uglification (mangle) with exceptions, block comments preserved, minification and a banner
            'src/input-a.js',
            'src/input-b.js',
            'src/input-c.js',
            'src/input-d.js',
            'src/input-e.js',
            'src/input-f.js'
        ]
    },
    concatenateOnly: {
        options: {
            compress: false,
            mangle: false,
            preserveComments: 'all'
        },
        files: 'dest/output.js': [ // only concatenation
            'src/input-a.js',
            'src/input-b.js',
            'src/input-c.js',
            'src/input-d.js',
            'src/input-e.js',
            'src/input-f.js'
        ]
    }
}
```

The `concatenateOnly` task would do exactly what you wanted, only concatenate. You could specify which files would be concatenated there. You could run both `concatenateAll` and `doAll` at the same time by using the `watch` task:

```
watch: {
    js: {
        files: ['config/*.js', 'app/js/**/*.js'],
        tasks: ['jshint', 'jasmine', 'uglify:concatenateOnly', 'uglify:doAll']
    }
}
```

...or you could do a single task by combining some of the settings I pasted above, like using the `options.mangle.except` to your benefit.

Comment: Wow, that's awesome. Forgot about the except option. You're guiding me through Grunt I see. :)

Comment: This solution is perfect. Excepting the little issue that due to an UglifyJS bug the `compress: false` parameter may not work: https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-uglify/issues/65.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you'll need two arrays, one with the list of files to be compressed and mangled and another to be concatenated.

The compressed and mangled array will be used on Uglify.

The concatenated array will be used on Grunt Contrib Concat.

Comment: I'm trying to avoid that because it creates temporary files that I have to remove afterwards with grunt clean.