# Gulp UglifyJs Skip Files

Tags: javascript, gulp, gulp-uglify

I am using Gulp UglifyJS and want to preserve function names for specific files.
Is there a way to not `mangle` certain files??
Does `mangle.except` accept a path?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22534524/can-i-tell-uglifyjs-to-only-compress-and-mangle-all-files-except-some-which-i-on

Comment: Thanks, not sure why I didn't find that in my search.... feel like a n00b.

Comment: I can't seem to get it to work with a path...